# Youtube Player API for Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm trying to use `YoutubePlayerView` in an Android `ListView`. Is it possible to have a `YoutubePlayerView` for each item of `ListView`? What should I do in order to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have a YouTube Player in each item of listview. As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), you need to migrate your application to use the `IFRAME API` or `embedded<iframe>players`. YouTube Android Player API enables you to incorporate video playback functionality into your Android applications. Using the API, you can load or cue videos into a player view embedded in your application's UI.

You need to initialize the [`YouTubeThumbnailView`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeThumbnailView). When ThumbnailView is initialized, app can get a callback to either `onInitializationSuccess` or `onInitializationFailure`. If it's a success then we put the Loader and setVideo which runs to the server to retrieve the Thumbnail.

For more information, you may use the Official Google Documentation including the sample Application:https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications

Comment: Thanks. I need to load a list of youtube videos but without thumbnails. It is gonna be the video itself instead of its thumbnails. The current video visible in the screen will be auto played and muted, something similar to Facebook feature. By using the YoutubePlayerView component for Android would that be possible?